# fixing bugs in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am totally new to the Bootstrap.
I am having the Following issues with my code and had spend many hours fixing them but couldn't find  an appropriate solution.
Here is my Code. http://www.codeply.com/go/cILzZnZ0Bs

### Issues :

1:) Above the Sign-In button there comes another white button with no function.I don't know what part in my code is causing that anonymous button.
2:)Even though I had added my media query for 582*1024 but still no effect is to be seen.the header "People things Recommendation" goes to the left of line "People Search".
I would be really Great if someone please help me out from this mess sorry in advance for any inappropriate code.
Here It should Look and be responsive in any screen size. [image]

Comment: help us out here, cause the view now is really unclear. can you update your post with a pic of how it should look?

Comment: @LiranBo edited. Here is it should look on all Screen Sizes following the White button removed and the Spacing between "Search" and "People" on 586*1024 screen Size.

Comment: The white button upper the Sign-in appeared because you wrapped the Sign-in with a button tag.

Comment: @HenryTran please can you elaborate in wrapping?What should i do for it?

Comment: `<button buttonid="btn1">
<a href="Signing Page/signin.html" class="btn btn-success"data-toggle="modal"data-target="#mymodal"type="button">

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">
</span> Sign In</a>
</button>`
The anonymous button that you said, it was the **button buttonid="btn1"**, just remove it, or change it into a div like this:
`<div>
<a href="Signing Page/signin.html" class="btn btn-success"data-toggle="modal"data-target="#mymodal"type="button">

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">
</span> Sign In</a>
</div>`

Comment: @HenryTran Thank you & please can you tell me why ain't my Media query working for a specific screen Size i had mentioned?

Comment: It works, I think the problem is your style code. Explain exactly what you want, I will try go give you the solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image: For the last issue, can you be more specific? what exactly do you want?]Okay so basically the button tag

```
    <button buttonid="btn1">
```

is causing the white blank button
and as for your media file ,displaying an ico file in an img tag is not guarenteed to work in all browsers(and i wouldn't recommend it). Convert the ico files to another format if you want to display them on the web.

Comment: Its not working by removing my buttonid  . You answer isn't following my requirements. I don't want to change my .ico file . I never mentioned that but i need to make a SPACING in between my Header in jumbotron at the size i had mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `.btn .btn-success` for a link, it will appear as a button. You don't have to use an additional `button` tag as you are using in your code.

Comment: could you please tell me what should i do in my code? Should i remove the button tag named "Signin"?

Comment: Yeah. Remove button tag `<button buttonid="btn1">` along with it's closing tag.

Comment: Thank You So much. and Please can you tell me why aint my Media query working for a specific screen Size i had mentioned? @niyasc